# about android: custom listview using activity or listfragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

i create a custom listview that contain 3 items

my question is how come when i used activity
if you want to create custom listview
you create 1st a layout for a single row and and inflate it inside other layout container

and when i used listfragment i dont need a parent layout container i just directly
used only the single row layout and i dont have to use any parent of it

i need explaination of it, i have no problem running it but i need info how
it runs without parent layout to put in single row layout of the listview
because in activity you need to setContentView the parent layout
but in listfragment how come i do it without a setcontentview and directly
inflate only the single row layout of the list view

Comment: Listfragment has a default layout which contains a listview and a textview

Answer (score 1):

If you use a ListFragment, ListFragment has a default layout that consists of a single, full-screen list in the center of the screen. You can have a custom layout but to do this, your own view MUST contain a `ListView` object with the id `"@android:id/list"` (or list if it's in code).

For the custom listview you have the listview and for each row in listview you inflate a custom layout. ListView is a view group that displays a list of scrollable items. So you have a custom adapter. In custom adapter getview you inflate your custom layout for rows in listview. you return the view. You set the Customadapter to listview. So listview has custom layout inflated for each row.

Also Listview recycles views. To know more check the below link's

[How ListView's recycling mechanism works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html. Same for ListFragment